# Chess and cube combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

A cube with sides equal to a field of a chessboard is sitting in the corner of one. Can we roll it all over the chessboard, visiting every field exactly once, so that there is a side of a cube that was never on the chessboard?

I'm having trouble deciphering the question, let alone do i now how 2 start.

Comment: [guess] It means put a cube of sidelength 1 over the corner of a chess board, where the six sides of the cube are labelled with numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6. A legal move from the cube being over a particular square of the chess board consist of pivoting the cube over one of the four sides of its lower face, until the cube ends up over one of the four squares adjacent to its present position (or three or two if it was at side or corner of board). During all the moves you keep track of all numbers which have at some time been the lower face of the moving cube. Your goal is to somehow hit all squares,

Comment: [continued] in such a way that one of the six labelled cube numbers has not ever been lowermost during the cube's movement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. Start with the cube in the corner on $0$ and roll it along the path below following the numbered steps. This is the first of many solutions found using a depth-first search.

\begin{matrix}0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
63&62&53&52&51&12&11&8\\
60&61&54&55&50&13&10&9\\
59&58&57&56&49&14&15&16\\
38&39&40&41&48&19&18&17\\
37&36&43&42&47&20&23&24\\
34&35&44&45&46&21&22&25\\
33&32&31&30&29&28&27&26\end{matrix}

Comment: how did ya find this sol.?

Comment: @LÜHECCHEgon [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)